# How to remove the first 2 letters of multiple file names in linux shell?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, png

I have files with the names:

```
Ff6_01.png
Ff6_02.png
Ff6_03.png
...
...
FF1_01.png
FF1_02.png
FF1_03.png
```

I want to remove the first two letters of every file name, because then I would have a correct order of the files. Does anyone know the command in the linux shell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the syntax `${file:2}` to refer to the name starting from the 3rd char.

Hence, you may do:

```
for file in F*png
do
   mv "$file" "${file:2}"
done
```

---

In case `${file:2}` did not work to you (neither `rename`), you can also use `sed` or `cut`:

```
for file in F*png
do
    new_file=$(sed 's/^..//' <<< "$file") <---- cuts first two chars
    new_file=$(cut -c3- <<< "$file")      <---- the same
    mv "$file" "$new_file"
done
```

#### Test

```
$ file="Ff6_01.png"
$ touch $file
$ ls
Ff6_01.png

$ mv "$file" "${file:2}"
$ ls
6_01.png
```

Comment: What exact command are you using? Are you in bash or shell? Which *nix?

Comment: @Kris you are not in bash. You are in some C-shell.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I was in csh then i Changed to bash and it worked!